# Prove that $n\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i.$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_n$ and $b_1 \leq b_2 \leq \cdots \leq b_n$, then prove that $$n\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i.$$

**Attempt**

The $n\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$ makes me think of Cauchy-Schwarz but I am not sure how to use it. I could use AM-GM to say  $n\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i \leq n\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{(a_i+b_i)^2}{4}$, but I am not sure how to relate that to the other terms.

Comment: Maybe need the restriction that the a's and b's are all nonnegative, or maybe all positive.

Comment: You don't. Maybe that is a hint to use the rearrangement inequality?

Comment: Induction works.

Comment: @Winther Yes, but there may be a more clever way using inequalities.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sum_{i=1}^n b_i - n \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i &=\sum_{i,j=1}^na_ib_j - n \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{i, j=1}^n(a_ib_j + a_j b_i) - \sum_{i, j=1}^n(a_ib_i +a_jb_j) \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i, j=1}^n(a_ib_j+a_jb_i-a_ib_i-a_jb_j)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i, j=1}^n(a_j-a_i)(b_j-b_i)\\
&\le 0.
\end{align*}